# R: glmer - Dimension Mismatch in multivariate analysis

Tags: r, statistics, lme4

I am using `glmer` from the `lme4` package in R to conduct a multivariate analysis.

My response variable is define as

```
rate <- cbind(A, B)
```

where `A` is the count of positive cases in a cohort and `B` is the total count of the cohort minus `A`.

The formula I am using is

```
glmer(rate ~ C + D + E + F + G + (1 | Z), family=poisson())
```

where `C` - `F` are 1 or 0, `G` is a count and `Z` is a factor with 6 levels.

When I run this model, I get the error `updateXwts: dimension mismatch`, but as far as I am aware, `glmer` supports multivariate analysis.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: I think you should be using the binomial family for this type of model; poisson isn't appropriate.

Comment: Okay, that fixes it. Can you elaborate or link me something that explains why a binomial distribution is better for this? `A` is definitely a Poisson distribution, so I sub-consciously made the assumption that combining `A` and `B` would also be Poisson.

Comment: It's because you have a fixed number of trials; a Poisson distribution has no upper limit.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this. I'm now scaling this problem up to use more random effects using MCMCglmm. Think you could lend another helping hand? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055240/r-alleged-missing-values-when-no-values-are-actually-missing-for-mcmcglmm