# R: Alleged "missing values" when no values are actually missing for MCMCglmm

Tags: r, mixed-models, mcmc

I have a data structured as follows:

- `A` is the count of positive cases in a cohort
- `B` is the total count of the cohort minus `A`.
- `C` is a binary variable
- `D`- `F` are normally distributed continuous variables
- `G` is 6 level factor

I am using MCMCglmm package in R to analyse this data to find which of the variables `C` - `G` affect `A` and `B`.

I have done this successfully using lme4's `glmer` function with success but now I wish to add more random effects which I have been advised will be better handled by the MCMC optimised variation. However, given the following function call

```
MCMCmod1 <- MCMCglmm(cbind(A, B) ~ C + D + E + F,
                     random = G,
                     prior = prior,
                     family ="multinomial2",
                     data = g)
```

(I appreciate the family may not be correct in this case)

Where

```
prior = list(R = list(V = 1, n = 0, fix = 1),
             G = list(
               G1 = list(V = 1, n = 1),
               G2 = list(V = 1, n = 1),
               G3 = list(V = 1, n = 1),
               G4 = list(V = 1, n = 1),
               G5 = list(V = 1, n = 1)))
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , response.names, value = c(0, 0, 0,  :
missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

However, when I check my variables there are 100% no NAs.

Any ideas on the steps I can take to try to debug this?

Comment: Have you got any empty factors?

Comment: By that do you mean is there an empty field for one of the rows in one of the factor type features?

Comment: I mean that if you created your factors and then subset your data, you might have a factor label that is empty. i.e `x <- factor(c("A", "B", "C")) ; y <- x[2:3]`. Now `y` contains 2 elements yet there are still three factor levels, and non of the elements belong to factor "A". This can sometimes cause your error message.

Comment: No this is not the case. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I don't have experience of using this package, but I have a feeling that `G` is used to specify the 'G-structure' of the model, so using this as a variable name as well might be causing a problem.

Comment: The variable names in the question are different from what I'm actually using, but nice idea.